# Installing Rcpp in rocker/r-devel-ubsan-clang

Tags: r, docker, rcpp

I'm trying to replicate CRAN sanitizer failures for my R package that depends on Rcpp on the rocker/r-devel-ubsan-clang docker image.

When I try to install Rcpp I get an error about `no type named 'R_ContinueUnwind'`. Is this something I'm doing wrong, or is it an incompatibility with Rcpp and Rdevel?

If the latter, is there a way to get a similar docker image that uses address sanitizers for a non-development version of R?

Here's the command I've been trying to run and output:

```
docker run --cap-add SYS_PTRACE --rm -it rocker/r-devel-ubsan-clang /bin/bash
root@e9f11aceb087:/# Rscriptdevel -e "install.packages('Rcpp')"
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.12.18.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3809164 bytes (3.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.6 MB

* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang++-4.0 -stdlib=libc++ -fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-sanitize=float-divide-by-zero -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize-address-use-after-scope  -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -mtune=native  -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
In file included from Date.cpp:31:
In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:128:
../inst/include/Rcpp/exceptions.h:150:7: error: no type named 'R_ContinueUnwind' in the global namespace
    ::R_ContinueUnwind(token);
    ~~^
1 error generated.
/usr/local/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:166: recipe for target 'Date.o' failed
make: *** [Date.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpqVuvlD/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rcpp") :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
```

#### Edit

Here's the result of `docker image list` and from within the container `Rdevel --version`

```
 docker image list rocker/r-devel-ubsan-clang
REPOSITORY                   TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
rocker/r-devel-ubsan-clang   latest              c769161f77fb        10 months ago       4.47GB
```

And `Rdevel --version`

```
Rdevel --version
R Under development (unstable) (2017-09-16 r73288) -- "Unsuffered Consequences"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

I got that image by using `docker pull`, I'm now trying to build it from scratch, following the lead that the image is 10 months old.

Comment: You could try `rocker/r-devel-san`, which has been build recently. The last build of `rocker/r-devel-ubsan-clang` is more than a year ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintainer of that repo here.  We could probably discuss that over at the repo in an issue ticket too.  I have not tried compiling R-devel with `clang` myself in some time (as I build r-devel at home via `gcc`), so not sure why the symbol is missing.

The whole concept was picked up by Winston who created a whole battery of debug Docker containers [in this repo](https://github.com/wch/r-debug).

Otherwise, the (excellent) [R hub builder](https://builder.r-hub.io/) also has sanitizer builds.  One remaining problem is that CRAN is not too forthcoming with changes to their setup (besides publishing their short descriptions) so it is never clear if the setup is in fact identical to theirs.

*Edit:* Actually `grep`'ing for your symbol shows that it is [contingent on R version 3.5.0 or later](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/exceptions.h#L149-L151):

```
#if (defined(R_VERSION) && R_VERSION >= R_Version(3, 5, 0))
    ::R_ContinueUnwind(token);
#endif
```

Can you double check your container setup if that is given?  We may have a mismatch here then between R version and R-devel version -- should be easy to fix.

Comment: Thanks! Posted here because I wasn't sure which repo - Rcpp or rocker? The tests pass on rhub (and r-devel-san), so was hoping to try something else.

Comment: Ah, we have a mess of multiple repos with Rocker and frequently get tickets in the wrong one :)  Oh well.   Well, if you have some spare cycles, I'd love to work with you on updating this.  The reference page for CRAN (UB)SAN setup should be unchanged and we should be able to get the same compiler versions if needed.

Comment: See update above, I think the problem is the image hosted on dockerhub is 10 months old, so it's a development version when R 3.5 was in development. Maybe someone just needs to hit update on the docker hub version?

Comment: Gotcha -- tickled a build, log will grow [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-devel-ubsan-clang/builds/bp2jamtc7uzxujbnxr9zeyv/).

Comment: And eventually it started and then finished so you can try it now.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, thanks for the explanation. Especially the comments regarding  CRAN being mysterious. I thought I was alone a few months back with a very similar issue that took me nearly 3 weeks to nail down.